# Can't get HttpPut action working

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an MVC app that talks to a web service (written in C#, and normally runs in Azure but I'm running it locally in IIS Express for debugging).  The web service exposes an API that supports HTTP GET and POST, and I'm trying to add PUT.  Currently all of the web service controllers have methods marked with either `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]` (with the parameters coming in as `[FromUri]` or `[FromBody]`, respectively).  I added a method to an existing controller and marked it `[HttpPut]`, with the parameter as `[FromBody]`.  It looks like this:

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateLastCheck(HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, [FromBody] RequestParameters requestParameters)
{
    return Process(httpRequest, (RequestParameters)requestParameters, DoUpdateLastCheck);
}
```

On the client side I call the API directly using jQuery $.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: "application/json",
    data: data,
    complete: completeCallback,
    success: function (data)
    {
        ...
    },
    error: errorCallback
});
```

What's happening is that the request isn't making it to my code.  It's being intercepted somewhere and I can't figure out where.  Running Fiddler, I see that the browser is actually making an OPTIONS request, and not a PUT request:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost/ViewPoint.Web.API/Notification/UpdateLastCheck HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:9999
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Connection: keep-alive
```

The server is responding with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 18 Sep 2013 22:21:20 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

PUT is not on that allow list, and I can't figure out why.  Is there something missing in my web.config file?  I can't even figure out how it builds that list - global search of the solution didn't turn up anything.

If I change everything to POST it works just fine (i.e. use `[HttpPost]` and call `$.ajax` with `POST`).  But we're trying to make our API as RESTful as possible, and for this particular action the appropriate verb to use is PUT.

Sorry if I didn't explain this well, this is my first web service API and I'm not sure what you guys need to know to diagnose the problem.  And if it is an IIS configuration issue, what's going to happen when I push to Azure?

UPDATE:  The problem does not occur if I use IE (10), only with FireFox and Chrome.  According to Fiddler IE makes a a PUT request directly, and that works.  FireFox and Chrome on the other hand make an OPTIONS request, the result of which is `Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST` (no PUT, so I guess that's why it doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by default, IIS Express does not support the **PUT** and **DELETE** verbs.  However, this can be remedied easily. The [IIS Express FAQ page](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-faq) shows us how.

1. The first step is to go to the IIS Express config directory. The path to this directory is `%userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\config`. Just enter this path in your explorer and it will open the config directory.
2. Open the `applicationhost.config` file in a text editor.
3. Search for the line that contains the following entry: `<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0"`
4. In that line, you will find the supported verbs. By default, the verbs attribute is configured as follows: `verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG"` You can see that there is no mention of the **PUT** or **DELETE** verbs. To add support for these verbs, simply add them to the `verb` attribute: `verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE"`
5. The last step is to restart IIS Express to have it pick up the changes in the config file.

After these steps have been executed, IIS Express will handle **PUT** and **DELETE** requests fine.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working.  I updated `ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_32bit`, `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit`, and `ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0` and set them all to "GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE".  I even rebooted the PC to make sure IIS got restarted.